# Problemas de serialização no .Net Core 3

Tags: asp.net-core, entidade-relacionamento

Estou estudando .NET Core API e tendo problemas com relacionamentos, onde recebo o erro sempre que eu tento listar todas as "calibrações" do "equipamento".

```
JsonException: A possible object cycle was detected which is not supported. This can either be due to a cycle or if the object depth is larger than the maximum allowed depth of 32.

System.Text.Json.ThrowHelper.ThrowInvalidOperationException_SerializerCycleDetected(int maxDepth)
```

Quando eu removo: "***.Include(c => c.Calibracao)***" do controle, recebo o json com "calibracao" nulo.

O que pretendo é obter todas as calibrações (Calibrado e Validade) de cada equipamento.

```
public class Equipamento
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Nome { get; set; }
        public int TipoEquipamentoId { get; set; }
        public TipoEquipamento TipoEquipamento { get; set; }
        public decimal Valor { get; set; }
        public string NotaFiscal { get; set; }
        public DateTime Entrada { get; set; }
        public List<Calibracao> Calibracao { get; set; }
    }

public class Calibracao
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int EquipamentoId { get; set; }
        public Equipamento Equipamento { get; set; }
        public DateTime Calibrado { get; set; }
        public DateTime Validade { get; set; }
    }

public class TesteContext : DbContext
    {
        public TesteContext(DbContextOptions<TesteContext> options)
            : base(options)
        {
        }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity<Calibracao>()
                .HasOne(p => p.Equipamento)
                .WithMany(b => b.Calibracao);
        }

        public DbSet<Equipamento> Equipamentos { get; set; }
        public DbSet<TipoEquipamento> TiposEquipamento { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Calibracao> Calibracoes { get; set; }
    }

// GET: api/Equipamento
        [HttpGet]
        public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<Equipamento>>> GetEquipamentos()
        {
            return await _context.Equipamentos
                .Include(t => t.TipoEquipamento)
                .Include(c => c.Calibracao)
                .ToListAsync();
        }
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O problema não está propriamente no relacionamento, mas sim na serialização, como é possível ver pelo seu tipo (`JsonException`) e também pela exposição do serializador utilizado (`System.Text.Json`).

Apesar de ter sido recentemente colocado como o serializador padrão, o `System.Text.Json` não está totalmente pronto para substituir o Json.NET (conhecido como Newtonsoft). Esse problema específico será tratado somente no .net 5 ([próxima versão do .net](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/archive/msdn-magazine/2019/july/csharp-net-reunified-microsoft%E2%80%99s-plans-for-net-5)), como é possível ver [neste issue](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/29900).

Para resolver o problema há 2 alternativas:

- usar uma [versão aplha do do System.Text.Json](https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/dnceng/public/_packaging/dotnet5/nuget/v3/index.json); ou
- voltar ao usar o Newtonsoft.

Diria que é mais seguro usar o antigo serializador. Para isso, adicione ao seu projeto o package [Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson) e configure-o da seguinte maneira:

```cs
services
    .AddMvc()
    .AddNewtonsoftJson(options => { options.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore; });
```

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente. Agora, será que consigo trazer o ultimo ou o primeiro registro de "calibração" de cada "equipamento"?

Comment: Diria para vc fazer uma nova pergunta sobre como criar este tipo de "relacionamento" no ef. Em pouco tempo deverá ter respostas.